# Collision Layer Matrix and Parent/Child object relationships

Tags: unity-game-engine

I come here after some testing, and because after some googling, I was incapable of finding a straight answer.

Suppose I have a player character with a tag set to `Player` and a layer set to `Humanoid`. I also have a bunch of NPC performing patrol, wander, and other movement behaviors. Their tags are set to `NPC` and their layers to `Humanoid`. Since this is a 2D game using 2D physics, I used the `Project Settings` collision matrix to make it so that `Humanoids` do not collide with each other.

In other words, the NPCs and the player characters can pass through each other, while respecting gravity, force, impulse, etc... This is working fine. My problem arises when: I want some child `GameObject` of NPC which is in layer `Default` and has a `CircleCollider2D` of type `Trigger` and I want to detect that collision in order to perform some actions (e.g.: show dialogue, stop or switch AI Behaviour of the parent object, or others).

From my testing, this seems not to be working, but I might be doing something wrong. So my question is:

- *If a GameObject **A** ignores collisions against layer X, will collisions against a GameObject **C** in layer Y be ignored if **C** is a child of a GameObject **P** in layer X?*

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
      if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        Debug.Log("Collided with player");
      }
      
      if (!eventConsumed && other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        var draw = Random.Range(0.001f, 1.0f);

        if (draw > 1.0f - eventChance) {
          dialogueEvent.Play();
          dialogueEvent = null;
        }

        eventChance = Mathf.Clamp(eventChance * 1.33f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a kinematic Rigidbody2D to the child GameObject and see if it works? If this presents a new issue where the child collides with its parent, then you can call [Physics2D.IgnoreCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. I added the Rigidbody with FronzenY and type kinematic to the child object, created a new Layer called HumanoidGFX, and set Humanoid Layer and Humanoid GFX layers not to interact with each other; While allowing HumanoidGFX to interact with Player and vice versa.

Comment: If you ignore collisions between layers Humanoid and GFX, how are 2 objects in these layers supposed to interact?

Comment: I want an Object in "Player Layer" to Ignore "Humanoid Layer" while accepting collisions against "Humanoid GFX". "Humanoid GFX" vs "Humanoid" ignore is for the rigid bodies not to bounce within each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to detect whether or not a physics collider that is set as a trigger has collided. You would need to use the OnTriggerEnter2D function instead of the OnCollisionEnter2D function.

Comment: This worked. I can not believe I wasted so much time on this. I totally forgot the existence of OnTriggerEnter2D.