# Unity: Detect Child Trigger inside Parent Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently learning how to make games in Unity and I want to detect when a Child's collider is being triggered to apply the damage to the thing being hit. But I'm confused about how it works.

- Does the Parent's `OntriggerEnter` detect the trigger event of the Child Object?
- And how do I know the trigger comes from the Child and not the Parent?
- And which Child's collider got triggered?

[image]

The Parent's collider is not triggered but the Child's collider is. Also the Child object doesn't have a rigidbody attach to it

Comment: Read up on layers, they can be used to separate collisions: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm going to answer it.
It's been answerd here as well I think :  [Collision Layer Matrix and Parent/Child object relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280629/collision-layer-matrix-and-parent-child-object-relationships).

If the child collision is not inside of parent collision you don't need to set `IsTrigger = true` for parent collision, just try different layers for you collisions.

Here is Unity documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Answer (score 0):

What you talk about is called self-collision. One way of handling this is to ignore certain colliders, take a look at the [documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html).

If I understood you correctly you have an GameObject hierarchy like so:

```
parentGO (contains player mesh and Capsule Collider 2D)
|-childGO (contains attack mesh and Mesh Collider 2D)
```

I'd attach to the `childGO` a script, which should register collisions on its polygon collider and notify the weapon script on the `parentGO` of the object being hit. The weapon can then deal the damage to the target.

Comment: I did think of this approach but then if I have for example multiple characters that use their child object colliders as a hitbox when attacking then I would need to create multiple control script for each one of the child object. Is there any other way to approach this problem that doesn't require a script in the child object ?

Comment: OnTriggerEnter is only triggered when the collider from the GameObject, where the script is attached has been intersected.

Comment: @Thien Collider have usually only one purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I know most likely You got your response, but It is also good to mention, that maybe You should think about separating these object and attaching them to new GameObject, that have a script holding both colliders - that might be more reliable and easy to read.

You can use `Collider2D.IsTouching(Collider2D other);`

[Here is documentation for IsTouching](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html)

Or write custom script that uses the observer and notify the main GameObject that the collision occurred.

```
private Action _onGameObjectCollided;
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
    if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("TAG")
        _onGameObjectCollided?.Invoke();
}
public void AddOnColliderEnterObserver(Action observer)
{
    _onGameObjectCollided += observer;
}

public void RemoveOnColliderEnterObserver(Action observer)
{
    _onGameObjectCollided -= observer;
}
```

And inside new GameObject:

```
collider.AddOnColliderEnterObserver(MethodToCallOnTriggerEntered);
```

Comment: What does `?.Invoke()` do ? I don't know how it work at all

Comment: You can think about the action as the method (more like set of methods) You pass as the parameter. The Invoke function is just calling this method(s). The '?' after action's name makes sure It is not a null (which normally would produce error). 
[You can read in the Unity's documentation about It.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityAction.html).